# How to configure Spark running in local-mode on Amazon EC2 to use the IAM rules for S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-spark-2.0

I'm running Spark2 in local mode on a Amazon EC2, when I'm trying to read data from S3 I'm getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively)

I can, but I rather not manually set the AccessKey and the SecretKey from the code because of security issues.

The EC2 is set with an IAM rule that allow it full access to the relevant S3 Bucket. For every other Amazon API calls it is sufficient but it seems that the spark is ignoring it.

Can I set the spark to use this IAM rule instead of the AccessKey and the SecretKey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to using the s3a:// scheme (with the Hadoop 2.7.x JARs on your classpath) and this happens automatically. The "s3://" scheme with non-EMR versions of spark/hadoop is not the connector you want (it's old, non-interoperable and has been removed from recent versions)

Answer (score 2):

I am using hadoop-2.8.0 and spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.

Spark-S3-IAM integration is working well with the following AWS packages on driver.

```
spark-submit --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3  ...
```

Scala codes snippet:

```
sc.textFile("s3a://.../file.gz").count()
```